# How to RowReduce a sparse matrix?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I want to compute the reduced row echelon form of a sparse matrix, but `RowReduce` returns a dense matrix. Is there a build-in function that computes the reduced form as a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The row echelon form of a general sparse matrix is not sparse.

However, there is a certain chance that the row echelon form of a suitable row/column permutation of the original matrix is sparse. This is what direct solvers for sparse arrays usually do when they perform a [sparse LU-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition).

A sparse matrix:

```
G = GridGraph[{300, 300}];
A = KirchhoffMatrix[G] + IdentityMatrix[VertexCount[G], SparseArray];
```

Generating a `LinearSolveFunction` `S` that stores the factorization:

```
S = LinearSolve[A, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
```

Lower triangular factor `L`, upper triangular factor `U` and permutation `p` can be obtained by

Retrieving the

```
L = S["getL"];
U = S["getU"];
{p, q} = S["getPermutations"];
```

The `"Multifrontal"` solver (here it is [UMFPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMFPACK) that is used as backend) attempts to find `p` and `q` such that the factors have small density:

```
A["Density"]
L["Density"]
U["Density"]
```

> 0.0000554074
>
> 0.000361489
>
> 0.000361489

We see that there is indeed quite a bit of *fill-in*, i.e., the factors are not as sparse as the matrix `A` itself.

Here you see how the permutations and the factors reproduce `A`:

```
Max[Abs[A - (L.U)[[p, q]]]]
Max[Abs[A - (L[[p]].U[[All, q]])]]
```

> 3.55271*10^-15
>
> 3.55271*10^-15

So, up to the permutations (and the fact that pivots are not normalized), the sparse row echelon form is `U`.